# Not found Error while running shell script

Tags: shell

I have written a shell script given below

```
unicorn_cnt=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c unicorn)
if (( $unicorn_cnt == 0 )); then
 echo "Unicorn Stopped" | mail -s "Alert - Unicorn" someone@somedomin.com
fi
delayed_job_cnt=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c delayed_job)
if (( $delayed_job_cnt == 0 )); then
 echo "Delayed Job Stopped" | mail -s "Alert - Unicorn" someone@somedomin.com
fi
rake_cnt=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c rake)
if (( $rake_cnt == 0 )); then
  echo "Convertion Stopped" | mail -s "Alert - Unicorn" someone@somedomin.com
fi
```

This is for checking, is the processes is running, if not send an alert mail. I am not much familiar with shell scripts. While running It shows following error.

```
process.sh: 3: process.sh: 2: not found
process.sh: 7: process.sh: 0: not found
process.sh: 11: process.sh: 0: not found
```

From some research I partially understands, this is because space problem while creating variable. Not sure. And I tried to use some solutions like **sed** and **read**. But still it showing the error. Can anyone help me.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets:

```
if [ "$unicorn_cnt" == 0 ]; then
```

Or better write it this way:

```
if ! ps -ef | grep -q [u]nicorn; then
 echo "Unicorn Stopped" | mail -s "Alert - Unicorn" someone@somedomin.com
fi
```

That means 'check ps -ef for unicorn, and if it is not found do this'

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay...... But showing an Error  "process.sh: 3: [: 2: unexpected operator"

Comment: Super! That means that your variable is empty. Use quotes around.

Answer (score 0):

For numeric comparisons you should use `eq` not `==`. 
Use `[[` for conditional expressions.
Use a [here string](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) rather than `echo` in your mail command.

Try this:

```
if [[ $unicorn_cnt -eq 0 ]]; then
    mail -s "Alert - Unicorn" someone@somedomin.com <<< "Unicorn Stopped"
fi
```

Comment: Sure I Changed "==" to -eq. How can we check less than in shell script. Is it **"-lt"**

Answer (score 0):

From the above tip I found my answer.

```
unicorn_cnt=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c unicorn)
if [ $unicorn_cnt -eq 0 ]; 
then
  echo "Unicorn Stopped" | mail -s "Alert - Unicorn" someone@somedomin.com
fi
delayed_job_cnt=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c delayed_job)
if [ $delayed_job_cnt -eq 0 ]; 
then
  echo "Delayed Job Stopped" | mail -s "Alert - Delayed Job" someone@somedomin.com
fi
rake_cnt=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c rake)
if [ $rake_cnt -eq 0 ]; 
then
  echo "Convertion Stopped" | mail -s "Alert - Convertion" someone@somedomin.com
fi
```

It is now working fine and we can Integrate it with cronjob also.

Comment: But better use "" around variables; and even better use ps + grep in if itself, without comparison; see my update